javafx hello world custom control works as expected in vscode but jar import in scenebuilder detects no UI
My Hello World Javafx Custom Control Works In Code but when i load the jar in scenebuilder,
it detects no UI component. I am using bellsoft java 21 full SDK with inbuilt javafx.scenebuilder version 22 with javafx 22 ( expected to work ok with java 17 and above). using VScode with java extension pack to debug and create jar file. while running vscode , the custom control works as expected .Created jar file in VSCode , when importing the control in scenebuilder .it detects no UI component with following exception . scenebuilder - custom library folder -  jar analysis report , shows following exception :-
Exception for: CustomArrowControl.class
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
unknown path
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.ExplorerBase.instantiateWithFXMLLoader(ExplorerBase.java:56)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.ExplorerBase.exploreEntry(ExplorerBase.java:111)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.exploreEntry(JarExplorer.java:83)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.util.JarExplorer.explore(JarExplorer.java:65)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.exploreAndUpdateLibrary(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:381)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.runDiscovery(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:155)
    at com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.kit.library.user.LibraryFolderWatcher.run(LibraryFolderWatcher.java:100)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    at javafx.fxml@22/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more

tried various answers from internet , but nothing seems to work . File ArrowFx.fxml as under :-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="118.0" prefWidth="447.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/22" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Rectangle fx:id="MyRect" arcHeight="5.0" arcWidth="5.0" fill="#1f1fff" height="63.0" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="28.0" stroke="#1f1fff" strokeType="INSIDE" width="273.0" />
      <Polygon fx:id="MyPoly" fill="#1f1fff" layoutX="285.0" layoutY="66.0" points="0.0, 46.00001525878906, 148.66668701171875, 2.6666641235351562, 0.0, -60.0" stroke="#1f1fff" strokeType="INSIDE" />
   </children>
</Pane>

File ArrowController.java as under :-
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;

public class ArrowController implements Initializable 
{
  @FXML private Polygon MyPoly;
  @FXML private Rectangle MyRect;

    @Override public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) // form load 
    {
     
    }

    public Rectangle GetRect() { return MyRect ; } 
    public Polygon GetPoly()   { return MyPoly ; }   
}

File CustomArrowControl.java as under :-
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty ;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;

public class CustomArrowControl extends AnchorPane  
{
  ObjectProperty<Paint> arrowColor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(Color.YELLOW) ;  
  ArrowController controller  ; 

  public CustomArrowControl() // Empty Constructor  
  {
     super();
     try 
     {
     // AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(Main.class.getResource("ArrowFx.fxml"));
     // FXMLLoader Loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/CustomArrowControl/ArrowFx.fxml"));  
     // FXMLLoader Loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/ArrowFx.fxml")); 

     FXMLLoader Loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ArrowFx.fxml")); 
     
     controller = new ArrowController();  
     Loader.setController(controller); 
     Node MYNode = Loader.load();
     this.getChildren().add(MYNode); 

     controller.GetPoly().fillProperty().bind(arrowColor);
     controller.GetRect().fillProperty().bind(arrowColor);

     } catch (IOException e) { }
  }  
  public ObjectProperty<Paint> getArrowColorProperty()  
  {
    return arrowColor;
  }
  public void setArrowColor(Paint color) 
  {
     arrowColor.set(color);
  }
  public Paint getArrowColor() 
  {
     return arrowColor.get(); 
  }
} 

jar tf CustomArrowControl.jar :-
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dstdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dstderr.encoding=UTF-8
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ArrowController.class
ArrowFx.fxml
CustomArrowControl.class
StartApp.class

tried running scene builder in command prompt , being on windows11 got no error messages

You seem to have your classes in the unnamed package. Perhaps that's the problem? Try moving them into named packages.

Worked. Thanks. In VSCode to run and debug java application , package need not be created , folder name is used as the package name of not defined , that caused the problem in my case. Thanks Again .
